# Unable to Convert Figma design to react

Tags: reactjs, figma

I am trying to convert a basic success page design from figma to reactcode using anima.

```
import React from "react";

function success() {
  return (
    <Frame1
      ellipse2="https://anima-uploads.s3.amazonaws.com/projects/602653dc8a60ddf32d89b719/releases/602653e5fdd0d169563cc04a/img/ellipse-2@2x.svg"
      ellipse1="https://anima-uploads.s3.amazonaws.com/projects/602653dc8a60ddf32d89b719/releases/602653e5fdd0d169563cc04a/img/ellipse-1@2x.svg"
      maskGroup="https://anima-uploads.s3.amazonaws.com/projects/602653dc8a60ddf32d89b719/releases/602653e5fdd0d169563cc04a/img/mask-group@2x.svg"
      great="Great!"
      text1="Your payment was successfull"
      place="Okay"
    />
  );
}

export default success;


function Frame1(props) {
  const { ellipse2, ellipse1, maskGroup, great, text1, place } = props;

  return (
    <div className="frame-1">
      <div className="overlap-group1">
        <img className="ellipse-2" src={ellipse2} />
        <img className="ellipse-1" src={ellipse1} />
        <div className="typcntick smart-layers-pointers ">
          <img className="mask-group" src={maskGroup} />
        </div>
        <h1 className="great avenirnext-medium-black-48px">{great}</h1>
      </div>
      <div className="text-1 avenirnext-medium-black-24px">{text1}</div>
      <div className="overlap-group">
        <Rectangle1 />
        <div className="place avenirnext-demi-bold-white-36px">{place}</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}


function Rectangle1() {
  return <div className="rectangle-1 smart-layers-pointers "></div>;
}
```

I have copied the jsx and css files from anima and now I am trying to import that into my app.
But I am unable to display it on my app. How can I resolve this?

```
import React from 'react';
import  './success.css';
import success from './success';

const App = () => {

  return (
    <div>
      <success/>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: What's the error?

Comment: @Dominik My react app is not showing anything. It's blank.

Comment: The bottom code you shared is irrelevant it seems. You're running the upper example?

Comment: @Dominik Yeah i edited it. Still i am getting the same blank page.

Comment: When I run your code above I get a bunch of green cycles and some text. Certainly not empty... https://codesandbox.io/s/crazy-sutherland-n8qfz?file=/src/App.js

Answer (score 0):

I checked the react code and it works for me, maybe there's something basic that is not setup correctly. First thing is to try and see if your react code shows a simple hello world text.

I see that you are using anima to import figma and export react code. If you manage to get it work that's great, if not I recommend trying Desech Studio and see if that works for you.

It imports Figma with relative html/css positioning and it exports react code. Here's the [github repo](https://github.com/desech/studio-react) for more details.

Answer (score 0):

The success component you imported and exported should start with a capital letter like Success then only react understands that its a component